# How to run a screenshare call while sending audio from PC and MIC to others?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I am running a game on my pc (jackbox party pack), and I need to screenshare it to the others for them to see the screen. Additionally I am wearing a headset with mic to listen to audio. The issue is the game has audio playing that the others need to hear. At the same time whatever I say on my mic, they also need to hear. Is there a way like a setting or tool I could use to do this? The screenshare tool could be anything like hangouts, zoom, discord, etc... whatever works best for this.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. in zoom you can "share computer audio" so others will also hear your game.

I've never tried that and not sure whether you can share computer audio and your voice at the same time, if not, then you'll need to join also with your phone to be able to speak to the others.

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362643-Sharing-Computer-Sound-During-Screen-Sharing?mobile_site=true